# How to enable bold fonts in sublime text2 in linux?

Tags: sublimetext2

I need to enable bold fonts in sublime text 2. I tried font_options but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: Did you try using : 
"font_options" : ["bold"]

Comment: This is not the best documented part of Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 38):

Add the following to your `Preferences.sublime-settings` file:

```
{
    // Valid options are "no_bold", "no_italic", "no_antialias", "gray_antialias",
    // "subpixel_antialias" and "no_round" (OS X only)
    "font_options": ["bold"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `no_italic` is valid, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Some fonts don't have true bold variations. ([Here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8411)'s a post on the Sublime Text forum explaining it.) Try using "DejaVu Sans Mono" or "Courier New", these will work in any case.